# consulta base de datos usando servlet

Tags: java, mysql, web, jsp

Cordial saludo

Buenos dias

estoy intentando imprimir una consulta para saber si funciona usando servlet para probar la consulta desde el servlet , pero cuando imprimo no muestra nada , si me pueden colaborar o si estoy implementando mal la consulta o la cadena de conexion a la que me estoy conectando

el codigo en el servlet para la consulta  es

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
             response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             Connection conn = null ;
             Conexion cn = new Conexion();
             PreparedStatement ps =null;
             //PreparedStatement ps = null;
             ResultSet rs = null;
             
         try {
             String consulta = "SELECT  Id_estudiante, Name_users from estudiantes";
            conn=cn.getConexion();
             ps=(PreparedStatement) conn.createStatement();
             rs=ps.executeQuery(consulta);
             String datos="";
             while(rs.next()){
                 datos +=rs.getString(1)+""+rs.getString(2)+"\n";
             }
             out.print(datos);
             
            
             
         } catch (SQLException e) {
         }finally{
             try {
                 if(conn != null) out.close();
                 if(ps != null) ps.close(); 
                 if(rs != null) rs.close();
             } catch (SQLException e) {
                 System.out.println("Error 4: " + e);
             }
         }
         
         
     }
```

el codigo de la conexion a la base de datos es el siguiente

```
 public class Conexion  {
     private Connection conn;
     public  Connection getConexion()
     {
         String url="por seguridad pero aqui va la cadena de base de datos";
         try
         {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             
         }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
         {
             System.out.print("No se pudo establecer la conexion"+e.getMessage());
         }
         try{
             conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"administrador","administrador");
         }catch (SQLException e){
             System.out.print("No se pudo establecer la conexion"+e.getMessage());
         }
         return conn;
     }
   }
```

Comment: El problema es que al tener el catch vacío luego de hacer el query, no te enteras donde estuvo el problema. Quizá te estés equivocando en el nombre de una columna o algo así. Agregale aunque sea un printStackTrace() al `catch (SQLException e)` y podrás ver que ocurre, y si aún no lo puedes solucionar, entonces modifica tu pregunta y agrega el error/excepción que te esté tirando.

Comment: Y, obviamente, debes consultar el log del servidor para ver si aparecen los mensajes de error.

Answer (score 0):

El primer punto de observacion es que no es buena tecnica cargar una clase cada vez que haces una instance del objeto utilizando Class.forName
La siguiente clase tiene un metodo static que llama a LOADERDRIVER solo 1 vez cuando se instance la aplicacion.

```
 public class Conexion {

    private Connection conn;
    private static boolean DRIVERLOADED = false;
    private static String LASTERROR = "";

    static {
        LOADDRIVER();
    }

    private static synchronized void LOADDRIVER() {
        try {
            if (!DRIVERLOADED) {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                DRIVERLOADED = true;
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            LASTERROR = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConexion() {

        LOADDRIVER();

        if (!DRIVERLOADED) {
            conn = null;
            return conn;
        } else {
            try {
                String url = "por seguridad pero aqui va la cadena de base de datos";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "administrador", "administrador");
                return conn;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                conn = null;
                LASTERROR = ex.getMessage();
                return conn;
            }
        }

    }

    public static String GetLastError() {
        return LASTERROR;
      
    }
```

Cuando creas el objeto puedes hacer esto.

```
Conexion cn = new Conexion();
if (cn==null){
System.out.println(Conexion.GetLastError());
}else{
//CONTINUAS CON TU CODIGO AQUI.
}
```